# Username and Password not accepted

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer, smtpclient

I'm trying to send a email using gmail's smtp (see below code) but I'm getting "Username and Password not accepted" error.

I've tried:

- [`this link`](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)
- [`allow less secure apps`](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
- ssl is enabled
- enable imap/pop on gmail's settings
- a different login

none of them works.

Here's the PHP code:

```
function sendEmail($from, $fromName, $msg)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 4; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                       // 1 = errors and messages
                       // 2 = messages only
    $mail->WordWrap    = 900; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line
    $mail->IsSMTP();

    //$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587; //465
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'yyyyyyy';

    $mail->From = $from;
    $mail->FromName = $fromName;

    $mail->AddAddress('foo@gmail.com', ' ');

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Priority = 1;
    $mail->Timeout = 60;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; 
    $mail->Subject  = "subject here";
    $mail->Body = $msg;
    $mail->AltBody = 'testing..';
    $ok = $mail->Send();

    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();

    return $ok;
}
```

**Update:** [`Here's`](http://pastebin.com/VppesgT6) the full error message (with DebugMode = 4)

Comment: are you using a newly created gmail account? At some point google increased restrictions about how gmail accounts could be used for smtp

Comment: @MichaelColeman: The account has about 1 year. Where can I find more information about this new restrictions?

Comment: Try creating an app password instead of using your gmail one, https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords worked for me in the past.

Comment: ok, well if other email clients have been working with the gmail account using SMTP for the last year. I would say you're good on that issue. sorry I never came across doc's/info, just prompts from gmail as I set up an account. I ended up just using a different account that I knew google had "cleared"

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I'm trying to create but that page redirect to https://myaccount.google.com/ and I can't find how to create the pasword in there :*

Comment: Well, I switch to use Hotmail. It just worked fine on first try.

Answer (score 0):

After testing I got this to work by changing the host to include the tls prefix.

```
function sendEmail($from, $fromName, $msg)
{
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 4; 
$mail->WordWrap    = 900; 
$mail->IsSMTP();

//$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';
$mail->Host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; //465
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'yyyyyyy';

// Define o remetente
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $fromName;

$mail->AddAddress('foo@gmail.com', ' ');

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Priority = 1;
$mail->Timeout = 60;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; 
$mail->Subject  = "subject here";
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->AltBody = 'testing..';
$ok = $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

return $ok;
}
```

Comment: This is not the fix you're looking for. Setting tls in the `Host` param is exactly the same as setting it via the `SMTPSecure` property.